# How to create recipe (Yocto build environment) for Nodejs modules

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, cross-compiling, node-modules, yocto

I want to create a nodejs module's recipe to make the particular module part of my final build image in yocto build environment.

To be specific i want to create recipe for 'node-beacon-scanner' module.
Can i write .bb file which can install all the dependencies of 'node-beacon-scanner' module ?

Note : I have one custom board based on IMX6ULL processor, on which i can't use "npm install module-name". So i have to cross compile this for ARM environment.

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check out Yocto's documentation on [creating a recipe for an NPM package](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#creating-node-package-manager-npm-packages).

Is there anything you've already tried? Have you attempted to create a recipe that gave you errors?

Comment: Thanks hakskel, I gone through the link you have provided. I have started making recipe for "node-beacon-scanner" nodejs module. Right now facing some compilation issues. Will update here once any i make any progress.